# At the end of the game, can you play a route that is longer than your number of trains?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

A recent quandary came up with some friends in a game of Ticket to Ride.  If, in the last turn, you have the cards to play a route longer than the number of trains that you have left, can you do so?  Or are you limited by your number of trains?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**No**, you are limited to the 45 trains you started with.

From the [rules](http://cdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tt_rules_en.pdf), under Claiming a Route (emphasis mine):

> The player may claim a route on the board by playing a set of Train Car cards that match the color and length of the route and **then placing one of his colored trains on each space of this route**

If you do not have the trains available to place on each space needed then you may not claim the route.

This is also how Days of Wonder's electronic implementation works.